# Facing a problem to set up the emulator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following problem.....

```
Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
   int _counter = 0;dsggfsgfh;
                    ^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I'm a beginner with Flutter. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has junk words or sentences, check your line ended with `dsggfsgfh;` which might be added unfortunately. Just remove it this will work.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that it's a compatibility issue between flutter framework and engine. You can try and:

1. Upgrade flutter to the latest version
2. Create a new project
3. Copy the code from the old project in steps
4. If you have plugins from the old project, add them one by one as you run the emulator

(It's possible that a certain version of a plugin has a compatibility issue with flutter)